# About Layar Integration

Tags: android, sdk, layar

I am new to [Layar Technology.](https://www.layar.com/)

Recently I created a Layar account and downloaded the Layar SDK and integrated it in my Android app. Uptil this things were fine. But in order to test this app I need some test pages. while creating them I found in their documentation about 'API endpoint', what is this actually? (In their documentation mentioned [here](https://www.layar.com/documentation/browser/publishing-site/register-layer/).) Some questions are in my mind. Please answer them as am not a Computer Graduate, I don't have much knowledge about servers and things like those. So I wonder:

Do we need a server to complete the Layar publishing?

If yes, then that means there should be a PHP page where you need do some PHP coding to receive the 
POI's they mention. Which means API endpoint URL is a link to this php page. Right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming here late after your question was asked, but in case someone finds this topic and asks himself the same question:

I THINK you're right I am trying to make an app using Layar and I am wondering how exactly it works aswell, but as you can see on some of the tutorials you can find on the documentation part of their website, it seems Layar requires that you use your own server to host your webservices.

(here's a link to one of their tuto as an example, there is a sample code downloadable it's written in PHP and you're supposed to put it on your server, and to give a link of your server on the "publishing layer" part of Layar to use the application with your own webservice.)
http://layar.pbworks.com/w/page/44331092/First%2520Layar%2520Tutorial%2520-%2520Create%2520a%2520simple%2520Geolocation%2520layer

Also to answer the API endpoint question here's how it is defined by Layar employees:

"• The URL for your web service that provides Spots. NOTE that only ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) are supported, so URLs with additional port info won't work."
or also 
"The URL for the web service that provides information about points of interest (POIs) in the database."

It is described as mandatory to use the service.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't base your answer on a link: if the site goes offline or the link changes, your answer will become useless. Instead, use the info on the site to build your answer and post the link as reference only. Thanks.

Comment: Tried to edit it a bit, I hope it's a little bit better, I will try to comeback on here to provide a solid answer to this question when I get better experienced with Layar myself.

Also to answer the API endpoint question here's how it is defined by Layar employees: 

"• The URL for your web service that provides Spots.
NOTE that only ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) are supported, so URLs with additional port info won't work."
or also
"The URL for the web service that provides information about points of interest (POIs) in the database."
It is described as mandatory to use the service.